# importing encryption key to google cloud key-management

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I want to import the encryption key to GCP "key-management" currently the key is on my GCP storage. are there any steps to import to GCP key-management without affecting the operation? if any on did before. thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

I found [this video](https://youtu.be/38_dWxOHUN8) useful.

In [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/kms/docs/importing-a-key#before_you_begin) they recommended that you create a new project to test this feature, to ease clean-up after testing and to ensure that you have adequate IAM permissions to import a key.